# Could not run Flutter app after a long time

Tags: flutter, dart, version

i have developed an application before two months, i need to add a new feature today so i opened the project to day. but i cannot compile the project , it throws errors only and i don't understand how to resolve it. i have cached_network_image , youtube_player_flutter packages.

i have pasted my error log below

```
Compiler message:
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/youtube_player_flutter- 
5.2.0/lib/src/player/raw_youtube_player.dart:55:30: Error: Getter not found: 'suspending'.
  case AppLifecycleState.suspending:
                         ^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/flutter/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 
780

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/flutter/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero 
exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to 
get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not get unknown property 'ANDROIDX_WARNING' for project ':youtube_player' of type 
org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to 
get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: try updating all the dependencies to latest version.

Comment: when i updated to latest version some of the parameters removed by the developer , so my code is getting errors

Comment: try to update flutter and make relevant changes then.

Comment: you need to create new project and deploy your code to it, with the last versions of packages [wiki](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-Flutter-projects-to-build-with-gradle)